# Props. is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```js
// how I called the component
<PriceInput
  editable={props.state.repeat}  
  freqchange={(e) => onChange("freq", e.target.value)}
  datefreqchange={(e) => onChange("freqdate", e.target.value)}
/>

// the component
const PriceInput = ({ value = {}, onChange, editable }, props) => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState("day");

  const triggerChange = (changedValue) => {
    onChange?.({
      number,
      currency,
      ...value,
      ...changedValue
    });
  };
  const onNumberChange = (e) => {
    const newNumber = parseInt(e.target.value || "0", 10);

    if (!("number" in value)) {
      setNumber(newNumber);
      props.freqchange(newNumber);    // error here
    }

// props.state
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
  repeat: false,
  freq: null,
  freqdate: null
});
```

The code threw

```sh
props.freqchange is not a function
```

I have looked up solutions on StackOverflow but many of them are regarding class components. Just wanted to stress here that everything's written in function in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you add `console.log(props.freqchange)` just above the erroring line. What is logged to the console?

Comment: `props` is the _second_ parameter to your component function, which _isn't_ the props.

Comment: You are getting the props as second argument of function. Your component only get one argument that is props so change your PriceInput to have { value = {}, onChange, ...props})

Comment: @kaleidawave undefined (commented out `setNumber(newNumber);` and replaced it with `props.freqchange` with no arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're destructuring your props, so either destructure all or nothing.

```
const PriceInput = ({ value = {}, onChange, editable, freqchange }) => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState("day");

  const triggerChange = (changedValue) => {
    onChange?.({
      number,
      currency,
      ...value,
      ...changedValue
    });
  };
  const onNumberChange = (e) => {
    const newNumber = parseInt(e.target.value || "0", 10);

    if (!("number" in value)) {
      setNumber(newNumber);
      freqchange(newNumber);    // error here
    }

// props.state
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
  repeat: false,
  freq: null,
  freqdate: null
});
```

Above, you will need to change `props.freqchange(newNumber)` to `freqchange(newNumber)`

Below you will have to change all: `value`, `onChange`... to `props.value` `props.onChange`

```
const PriceInput = (props) => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState("day");

  const triggerChange = (changedValue) => {
    onChange?.({
      number,
      currency,
      ...value,
      ...changedValue
    });
  };
  const onNumberChange = (e) => {
    const newNumber = parseInt(e.target.value || "0", 10);

    if (!("number" in value)) {
      setNumber(newNumber);
      freqchange(newNumber);    // error here
    }

// props.state
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
  repeat: false,
  freq: null,
  freqdate: null
});
```

Comment: If I go with the first method, `freqchange={(e) => onChange("freq", e.target.value)}` returns "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: `console.log(e)` see what it returns